# Contract state variable change after throw

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, blockchain

Is there a possibility to change a state variable and then throw an error, so that the state is maintained. e.g.:

```
uint minAmount = 1 ether;
uint state;
function payDeposit() payable {
    if(msg.value < minAmount ) {
        state = 2;
        throw;
    }
    state = 1;
 }
```

In the example above, the state variable is not set. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, since `throw` ensures that there are no side effects of the call remain and all gas is consumed.

Comment: I belivev you could use one of require(msg.value < minAmount or assert(msg.value < minAmount) ...I forget which of the two will maintain state.